# Javascript Variable class or id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in .js file and when you add class on html like open-product it opens product-popup.

```
$('.open-product').on('click', function(){
        showPopup($('#product-popup'));
        initSwiper();
        return false;
    });
```

But I wanna use like this..

```
 $('.open-product(product id variable)').on('click', function(){
        showPopup($('#product-popup(product id variable)'));
        initSwiper();
        return false;
    });
```

Its for multiple products on I html page. when I click 45. product like open-product45 it has to open product-popup45.

How should be this javascript code?

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a data attribute to your HTML :

```
<div class="open-product" data-product_id="1"></div>
```

Then in your JS :

```
$('.open-product').on('click', function(){
     var product_id = $(this).data('product_id');
     showPopup($('#product-popup'+product_id));
     initSwiper();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: I did what you said but it doesnt working. And I add like this

<div id="product-popup1"

Comment: Its not opening the popup

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
var productId = 1;

$('.open-product' + productId).on('click', function(){
        showPopup($('#product-popup' + productId));
        initSwiper();
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using some parameter in your button.

```
<button class="open-product" data-product="1">Open product 1</botton>
```

JS

```
$('.open-product').on('click', function(){
        showPopup($('#product-popup-' + $(this).data('product')));
        initSwiper();
        return false;
    });
```

Or even consider refer to pop-up id like this:

```
<button class="open-product" data-popup="#product-popup-1">Open product 1</botton>
```

JS

```
$('.open-product').on('click', function(){
        showPopup($($(this).data('popup')));
        initSwiper();
        return false;
    });
```